# How to add multiple values to a key of an array and get data from another table?

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to get data from one database with a condition where id equals to current logged in tenant (tenant_id),

```
$this->data['props'] = $this->property_m->get_by( array ('id' => $this->session->userdata['tanant_id'] ));
```

and then get some values from a field and save in an array,

```
if(count($this->data['props']) > 0){
    $my_array = array();
    foreach ($props as $prop){
        $my_array['id'] = $prop->tenant_id;
    }
}
```

First problem here - **$my_array consists only 1 value. ( I need it to be multiple ) How can I do that ?** 
Second problem - **I need to select data from another table which would look for data fulfilling the condition in that array,** as,

```
$this->data['reports'] = $this->report_m->get_by($my_array);
```

which would say,

```
SELECT * FROM  reports WHERE ('id = 1'); // or 2 or 3 (value from prop->tenant)
```

but I need it to be,

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE ('id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3');
```

Comment: 1. Don't overwrite key `id` every iteration. 2. `Where id IN ()`

Comment: Please tell me how not to overwrite key  id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing:

```
$my_array = array();
foreach ($props as $prop){
    $my_array['id'] = $prop->tenant_id;
}
```

You're just overwriting `id` key of `$my_array`. Use this:

```
$my_array = array();
foreach ($props as $prop){
    $my_array[] = $prop->tenant_id;
}
// print_r($my_array);
```

---

Use `where field in ()` condition:

`SELECT * FROM reports WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);`

Assuming you have:

```
$my_array = array(1,2,3);
// query string:
$q_str = 'SELECT * FROM reports WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $my_array) . ')';
```